# Delete SQLite Data from .db File and Update UITableView Using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, uitableview

**I am trying to delete the data from a sqlite table** using swift and remove the contents of UITABLEVIEW CELL.

Code shown below is working fine (no error). However, the problem is that when application is run next time , it populates the data from previous sql queries.

```
@IBAction func removeAllData(sender: AnyObject) {

           //deleting the data from arrays responsible for updating the labels in UITableView Cell

            self.endData.removeAll()
            self.startData.removeAll()
            self.driveData.removeAll()

        //Deleting the table
        let tripsDB = FMDatabase(path: recievedDatabasePath as String)

        if tripsDB.open(){
            let sqlQuery = "DELETE  FROM trips"
            let results : FMResultSet? = tripsDB.executeQuery(sqlQuery, withArgumentsInArray: nil)

            print(tripsDB.lastErrorMessage())

        } else {
            print(tripsDB.lastErrorMessage())
        }
        tripsDB.close()

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks a lot in advance.

***updated:***

```
let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let dirPaths = filemgr.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
databasePath = dirPaths[0].URLByAppendingPathComponent("trips.db").path!



//sending the database contents to table view controller. here the recievedDatabasePath Variable is equal to the current database path mentioned in the first view controller


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 
{
   if  segue.identifier == "historySegue" {         
     let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! HistoryTableViewController
    destinationViewController.recievedDatabasePath = databasePath
        }
     }
```

Comment: how you are getting path of db?

Comment: there are couple of possible problems in it. Like you database has data when you are running it in the simulator or device.

Comment: and when you run the application again it will copy db in device which contain data. There are also many other possibilities.

Comment: provide code which you are using to copy the db in the device document directory or NSBundle.

Comment: Thank you @AbdulRehmanWarraich for reply. What i am doing is that on the table view, sqldata is being loaded from a sqlitedb file which was created in the first view controller. i think that is the problem because the above func is clearing the file from current view controller however the first view controller db file still have the data

Comment: Here is the updated code as requested. Sorry for delay.

Comment: where are you creating SQLite DataBase in your project ?

Comment: And also take a look to the deletion query "DELETE  FROM trips". I think there should be where clause in the query.